# Como validar tipo Date com bean validation do Springboot?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, rest

Senhores, gostaria de saber de vocês, como estão validando campos do tipo Date no Spring-boot com Bean Validation?
Eu usei a anotação `@DateTimeFormat` mas não obtive o retorno esperado, além de não existir a propriedade `message` para personalizar a mensagem de retorno.
Até cheguei a criar um validador próprio, conforme abaixo:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateValidator.class)
public @interface DateValidation {

    String message() default "A data informada é inválida!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String value() default "";

}

public class DateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DateValidation, Date> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Date value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null || (DateUtil.isValidDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy") && DateUtil.isValidSQLServerDate(value))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public static boolean isValidDate(Date date, String dateFormat) {
    try {
        String strDate = parseToString(date, dateFormat);
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dateTimeFormatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isValidSQLServerDate(Date dateToCheck) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(1753, 0, 1); // 01-Jan-1753
    Date dataInicio = cal.getTime();

    cal.set(9999, 11, 31); //31-Dez-9999
    Date dataFim = cal.getTime();

    if (dateToCheck.compareTo(dataInicio) >= 0 && dateToCheck.compareTo(dataFim) <= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Mas a validação do spring nem chega a passar aqui. Segue a controler:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<InstrumentoAcesso> incluirInstrumentoAcesso(@RequestBody @Valid InstrumentoAcesso instrumentoAcesso, @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") String token) {
    return this.service.create(instrumentoAcesso, this.prepararRequest(token));
}
```

Gostaria de alguma luz a respeito, um vídeo, tutorial, informação, qualquer coisa que ajude.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muitas tentativas descobri o motivo de não passar no validador, minha entidade estava anotada com validadores do `javax.validation.constraints` mas, meu validador criei com as anotações de `jakarta.validation.constraints`, por esse motivo, o validador não funcionava. Coloquei tudo como `javax.validation.constraints`, e agora funciona!